# how to remove +universal

Tags: macports, universal

I wanted to install wine through macports. I followed instructions on following site: http://www.easypctutorials.com/how-to-install-wine-on-mac-os-x
Now when I try the sudo install command for anything, terminal first returns this:

```
Warning: /opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf specifies invalid variant syntax '“+universal”', ignored.
```

and then it always fails to install the software.
Now, I want to know how to remove +universal or what could be done to install wine or anything else otherwise. Even MacPorts doesn't get updated citing the same thing. Even if I search for ports, it says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line containing `+universal` from `variants.conf` (or clear out `variants.conf` completely) and skip this step of the how-to. It is no longer needed, MacPorts will automatically ensure the dependencies are available in the correct architecture when you attempt to install wine.